# Create instance using a string instead class name

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to instance a class depending on a combobox selection. Let say I have the following classes and interface:

```
Public Interface Sports
Sub description()
End Interface

Public Class Football : Implements Sports
Public Sub description() Implements Sports.description
    MsgBox("Football")
End Sub
End Class

Public Class Hockey : Implements Sports
Public Sub description() Implements Sports.description
    MsgBox("Hockey")
End Sub
End Class
```

One solution for my client looks like:

```
    Dim test As Sports

if combobox.selectedtext = "Football" then
test = New Football
else
test = New Hockey
end if

test.description()
```

With many subclasses this can be quite long, so I was thinking about a way to instance the chosen class depending on the selected text. I know this looks stupid, but something like:

```
Dim text As String = ComboBox1.SelectedText
test = New "test"
```

Is it possible to instance a class depending on an assigned string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Activator.CreateIntance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx) method to create a new instance.

This method requires a `Type` be passed in, so if you only have the string, you'll need to combine the method with [Type.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(ComboBox1.SelectedText))

You'll then need to cast the returned `Object` to `Sports` if you want to assign it to your variable.

**Note:** The ComboBox will need to list the full type name (name and namespace) otherwise `Type.GetType` will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically instantiate a type based on its unqualified name by searching for the type:

```
// Find the type by unqualified name
var locatedType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                          .GetTypes()
                          .FirstOrDefault( type => type.Name == "Football" );

// Create an instance of the type if we found one
Sports sportsInstance = null;
if( locatedType != null ){
    sportsInstance = (Sports)Activator.CreateInstance( locatedType );
}
```

This will search the current assembly for a type matching the name "Football" and instantiate it if it was found.